# Playback fails on iOS and Mac-Safari for HLS url that has colon

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am testing my hls.js-based player with a content url that has a colon in it:

`https://video.mysite.com/97215bca-58d9-4fdb-bccd-ecca1f6c4bce/smil:ABC_ABCDEFGHIJ.smil/playlist.m3u8`

This works fine for Chrome/Firefox/Edge on Windows and works on Android too.

However, when I try playback on Mac Big Sur Safari 14 or iOS 14 it fails to fetch any media chunks. I get a successful response for the playlists:

```
GET https://video.mysite.com/97215bca-58d9-4fdb-bccd-ecca1f6c4bce/smil:ABC_ABCDEFGHIJ.smil/playlist.m3u8
200 OK
GET https://video.mysite.com/97215bca-58d9-4fdb-bccd-ecca1f6c4bce/smil:ABC_ABCDEFGHIJ.smil/chunklist_b1128000.m3u8
200 OK
```

The chunklist content looks fine

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:714
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:4.004,
media_b1128000_714.ts
#EXTINF:4.004,
media_b1128000_715.ts
#EXTINF:4.004,
media_b1128000_716.ts
```

But depending on the iOS device either I never see any requests for the media*.ts files, or they show up as cancelled (appear to timeout). The player eventually gets a decode error.

The player uses hls.js for playback on most devices (all the working ones), but on iOS and I believe Safari it uses built-in Apple HLS playback. My theory is that engine does not like the colon in the url, but I don't have any control over that format. Has anyone experienced any issues like this with Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the content of the m3u8.

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1128000,CODECS="H264,AAC",RESOLUTION=1024x576
```

Apple devices didn't like the CODECS that were being specified. The provider removed the CODECS part and the playback started working.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  Unfortunately, if you omit CODECS, Firefox won't play anything.  So there has to be some magic value that both browsers will accept, given that they both handle the content correctly if you provide them with slighly different metadata.  I'd love to know what that is, though, because nothing I try works.